# Create table with a restriction for a Reasonable date SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am here because I'ven having serious issues finding an answer to this question. My doubt is: 
I have created the following two tables (I omit a few things because I don't think it is useful to write everything here):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE PRESTAMO (
num_prestamo NUMBER(9),
fecha_prestamo DATE,
fecha_devolucion DATE, 
tipo VARCHAR(16) CONSTRAINT tipo_nnull NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT tipo_ck CHECK (tipo='Prestamo en sala' OR tipo='Prestamo externo')
);
```

And, this one:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE SOLICITA (
num_prestamo NUMBER(9) REFERENCES PRESTAMO(num_prestamo),
isbn NUMBER(9) REFERENCES LIBRO(ISBN),
fecha_solicitud DATE,
);
```

What I want to do is to set a restriction so that fecha_solicitud<=fecha_prestamo.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks for completing the 2-minute site tour. So many people don't, so good job on that at least.

Comment: What is `fecha_prestamo`? I don't see it in either table. Presumably it is a column you didn't show in the first table. Constraints ONLY exist on rows from a single table, so this won't work.

Comment: I've just added the missing column.

Comment: T-Heron, I don't understand what you mean when you say "code snippet", because I am already showing what I've got.

Comment: Are the tables related somehow? Perhaps num_prestamo is primary key in the first table and foreign key (pointing to the first table) in the second table? You clearly need a "join condition" between the two tables (otherwise how are you restricting the date from one row in one table compared to the date from... which row... from the other table?)

Comment: I think you need to do this via a trigger or user defined function.

Comment: The tables are related through the column "Num_prestamo". 
The process is this:
 1. Someone goes to the library, and asks for a book (SOLICITAR = ASK FOR).
 2. If the book (libro) is avaliable, then it will be lend (Lend=prestar), so this day will be fecha_prestamo (fecha prestamo = lending day). 
3. If the book is not avaliable, the person will have to wait, but there will be a DATE registered, so if many people ask for the same unavaliable book, the one with the oldest fecha_solicitud will be the first in recieving the book. 
Perhaps it would be better: fecha_prestamo>=fecha solicitud

Comment: So, is it possible to set that restriction?

I think I will set a default value "sysdate" for fecha_solicitud.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you could use trigger to do that

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOLICITA_b4_in_up
    BEFORE INSERT or update 
       ON SOLICITA 
       FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
       my_fecha_prestamo date;
    BEGIN  
       select fecha_prestamo into my_fecha_prestamo 
              from PRESTAMO where num_prestamo = :new.num_prestamo;

     if my_fecha_prestamo < :new.fecha_solicitud then 
            Raise_Application_Error (-20050, 'Date constraint violated'); 
     end if;     
    END;
/
```

Comment: @AlexisPermuy Welcome, did it help / work? if it did, then please upvote / accept the answer...

Comment: I upvoted, but I still do not have enough reputation for it to be counted as a vote.

Comment: @AlexisPermuy OK ;-) Never mind .. what matters is that you solved your problem... I'll up vote your question to give your reputation some boost ;-) Take care ...